# Not able to call hammer js instance after the latest update

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am not able to call Hammer instance after the update to latest version 2.0.4
I am using Require JS. I am using

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement, myOptions);
```

But this doesn't work any more. Can anyone suggest new working method for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble before I got around it by doing:

```
$('h1').hammer().on('press', function(ev) {
   console.log('press')
});
```

I also included the script at the bottom of this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/annam/xGJZL/

that seemed to work for me.